# Integral (complex) of the function $(1-\cos(x))/x^2$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I can't seem to find a procedure to solve the following exercise:

Find the value of $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1 -\cos (2\pi x)}{x^2} dx = k\pi^2$$

I tried integrating on semicircles in $\mathbb{C}$ but that "$1 - \cos()$" always gives me problems.

Comment: It more useful this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmQiZ5ipAAA

Comment: Oh, It's exactly my integral! thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use identity $\cos2x = \cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$ to achieve
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1 -\cos (2\pi x)}{x^2} dx =\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{2\sin ^2(\pi x)}{x^2} dx=2\pi^2$$